# Is it possible for browser-hosted Javascript to alter html during page load?

Tags: browser, javascript

I can put [Javascript in TamperMonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/1661820/is-it-possible-to-run-a-custom-script-whenever-loading-a-web-page-on-web-browser) to tamper with the HTML.  Does it process the HTML as it is received, or does it alter the DOM after it is fully loaded?

I want to alter links that contain tracking parameters to be the actual original URI.

Example: post

```
https:/somplace.com
```

and Facebook shows everyone that, but makes it a link to

```
https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsomplace.com%2F%3Ffbclid%3DXX&__tn__=YY&c[0]=ZZ
```

where XX, YY, and ZZ are things that help them and others track us.  I want to remove the `https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=`, change `fbclid`, `__tn__`, and `c[0]` to "tracker" and unescape the original URI.

Safari has features that reduce tracking, but it doesn't catch this.  Firefox doesn't catch it either.

Comment: I have fbpurity in Safari, and I just found code in it that should do what I want, but it isn't working.